# How to select rows from data frame using grep() in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to select rows from a data frame based on the content of one of the columns. I am using grep() but when trying to match for the end of the content it only matches the last pattern that was submitted.

This is the code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cName=c(
    'A Co', 'B Co',  'C Co', 'D Co', 
    'F Llc', 'G Llc', 'H Llc', 'I Llc',
    'P Inc', 'Q Inc', 'R Inc', 'S Inc'))    
tName <- grep( ("Inc$ | Llc$"),df1$cName, value = T)
tName
[1] "F Llc" "G Llc" "H Llc" "I Llc"
```

I am expecting it to return all the occurrences of `'Inc' and 'Llc'`.  However, only the last one in the regular expression is returned.  I have tried various combinations with brackets, parenthesis and `[:space:]` without success.  What is wrong?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Ditch the white spaces they have meaning. In other words, just do `grep("Inc$|Llc$",df1$cName, value = TRUE)`. Or in case space is important, do `grep(" Inc$| Llc$",df1$cName, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [the code that works](http://goo.gl/OhzMg8) as expected:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cName=c(
    'A Co', 'B Co',  'C Co', 'D Co', 
    'F Llc', 'G Llc', 'H Llc', 'I Llc',
    'P Inc', 'Q Inc', 'R Inc', 'S Inc'))    
tName <- grep( ("(Inc|Llc)$"),df1$cName, value = T)
tName
```

Output: `[1] "F Llc" "G Llc" "H Llc" "I Llc" "P Inc" "Q Inc" "R Inc" "S Inc"`

The original regex did not work as expected because it required a space after a string end anchor, which is just not possible. You can see the [regex explanation at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aO0vQ8/1).